# postgres: how to use result of a text[] function as parameters in a SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function that gives me a `text[]` as a result, output looks like this

```
tables_array                                     
----------------------------------------------------
{mon11,mon10,mon9,mon8,mon7,mon6,mon5,mon4,mon3,mon2,mon1}
```

now I wanted to use that output in another functions `SELECT`

```
SELECT 
     tables_array('1') 
from 
     abc;
```

but I got

```
{mon11,mon10,mon9,mon8,mon7,mon6,mon5,mon4,mon3,mon2,mon1}
```

for every entry in table `abc`

so I used

```
SELECT 
     array_to_string(tables_array('1'), ',') 
from 
     abc;
```

but now I get

```
tables_array                                     
----------------------------------------------------
mon11,mon10,mon9,mon8,mon7,mon6,mon5,mon4,mon3,mon2,mon1
```

for every entry in table `abc`, again

I did try several combinations with other `SUBSELECTS`, it either ended in syntax errors or false results.

**EDIT 1:** I would expect the result to look something like:

```
mon11   mon10     mon9      mon8 
--------------------------------
0.070   0.0013    0.091908  0.26
```

**EDIT 2:**

fixed some wrong function naming

Comment: Do you want get first element from array, when you try `SELECT tables_array('1') from abc` ?. is this your goal ?

Comment: no the '1' is how many years are returned from the function if I put in e.g.  a 3 then the return is mon11 ... mon1,y2015,y2014,y2013

Comment: So what result do you want?

Comment: If you don't `SELECT` any column of `abc`, why do you include it in `FROM`?

Comment: @pozs updated my question to show what I intend to get as a result

Comment: Please post the schema & example data for the `abc` table as well. Maybe you are looking for the [`crosstab` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html), but a simpler pivoting might be enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

show this example, maybe helpfull for you

```
select unnest((select array['ax','dsf','qwe']))
```

Comment: I tried unnest, but it simply repeats the above behavior unnest                                              
mon1                                                
mon2                                                
mon3                                                
mon1                                                
mon2                                                
mon3 from hoizontal to vertical

Answer (score 0):

This should work for using output values as parameters in another select:

```
select t.months[1] --to get first value
from abc h,
LATERAL(select * from tables_array())  t(months)
```

this will work as cross join.